# Return concrete type for a trait from it's companion object

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, typeclass

Previously I returned [concrete types from a trait](https://github.com/vasigorc/Algorithms/blob/master/Chapter%202%20Sorting/algorithms2_1/src/main/scala/ca/vgorcinschi/algorithms2_4/immutable/MaxPQ.scala#L21), but never from a companion object of a trait and couldn't find an example of my exact scenario online. Please feel free to point me if this is a duplicate.

I have this trait:

```scala
trait Problem[T <: ProblemInput] {
  // uses template pattern by calling abstract methods implemented in implementations
  def solve(problemInput: T): Solution = {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then a few implementations of it:

```scala
class DoubleCube extends Problem[Cube] {
  ...
}

class SquareCircle extends Problem[Circle] {
  ..
}
```

I want to be able to have a factory method to map a problem input to its problem, i.e.:

```scala
object Problem {

  def apply[T <: ProblemInput](problemInput: T]: Problem[T] = input match {
    case Cube(_,_) => DoubleCube()
    case Circle(_,_) => SquareCircle()
  }
}
```

The solution doesn't compile with the following error(example):

```scala
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : DoubleCube
[error]  required: Problem[T]
[error]   case Cube(_,_) => DoubleCube()
```

**Update**
Following @Tim's advice: I modified the code to provide a type class that would translate the mapping, so now the implementation looks as follows:

```scala
trait Translator[T <: ProblemInput] {
  def translate(pi: ProblemInput): Problem[T]
}

object TranslatorInstances {
  implicit val forCube: Translator[Cube] = (pi: Cube) =>
    new DoubleCube()
  implicit val forCircle: Translator[Circle] = (pi: Circle) =>
    new SquareCircle()
}

object Problem {
  def apply[T <: ProblemInput](pi: ProblemInput)(implicit
    translator: Translator[T]
  ): Problem[T] = translator.translate(pi)
  ...
```

This compiles, but ports the problem to the caller side:

```scala
def callerSide(pi: ProblemInput): Unit = {
  val problem = pi match {
    case Cube(_,_) => Problem[Cube](pi)
    ...

  }
  problem.solve(pi)
  ...
}
```

The compiler complaints that:

```sh
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : ProblemInput
[error]  required: _1
[error]       problem.solve(pi)
[error]                     ^
[error] one error found
```

Comment: You probably want to create a typeclass that constructs a `Problem` based on a particular `ProblemInput` type.

Comment: Thanks @Tim that changed the error. I updated the ticket to describe the change.

Comment: You don't need the `match` on the caller side, just use `val problem = Problem(pi)` and the typeclass will match the right version of `Translator`. (but `pi` in the `apply` method should be `T` not `ProblemInput`)